# Mudar cor do Input ao digitar x caracters

Tags: javascript, input

Eu gostaria que quando uma pessoa digitasse mais de 10 caracteres no meu *input*, ele trocasse a cor pra verde, caso contrario fica vermelho.

Isso sem da *refresh*. A pessoa não precisaria clicar no botão para poder alterar as cores. Eu gostaria que alterasse as cores enquanto a pessoa tivesse digitando mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar o evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) no *JavaScript*. Com ele você poderá detectar todas as alterações do campo.

**Exemplo com *JavaScript* "Puro":**

```js
/* Captura o campo */
const fieldMessage = document.querySelector("#message")

/* O evento INPUT irá detectar todas as alterações no valor digitado/colado */
fieldMessage.addEventListener("input", _ => {

  /**
   * Verifica se o valor digitado possui mais de 10 caracteres
   * Caso possua, adiciona a classe `valid`
   */
  if (fieldMessage.value.length > 10) {
    fieldMessage.classList.remove("invalid")
    fieldMessage.classList.add("valid")
  }
  /* Caso contrário remove-a */
  else {
    fieldMessage.classList.remove("valid")
    fieldMessage.classList.add("invalid")
  }
})
```

```css
input.valid {
  /* Altera a cor da borda */
  border: 2px solid green;
  
  /* Altera a cor da sombra */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
}

input.invalid {
  /* Altera a cor da borda */
  border: 2px solid red;
  
  /* Altera a cor da sombra */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="message" />
```

**Exemplo com *jQuery*:**

```js
/* Captura o campo */
const fieldMessage = document.querySelector("#message")

$("#message").on("keyup", function(){
  if ($("#message").val().length > 10) {
    $(this).addClass("valid").removeClass("invalid")
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("invalid").removeClass("valid")
  }
})
```

```css
input.valid {
  /* Altera a cor da borda */
  border: 2px solid green;
  
  /* Altera a cor da sombra */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px green;
}

input.invalid {
  /* Altera a cor da borda */
  border: 2px solid red;
  
  /* Altera a cor da sombra */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="ex" onBlur="ts()">
<script>
  function ts(){
 var a = document.getElementById('ex').value;
 var b = a.length;
if(b<10)
    document.getElementById('ex').style.background ="red";
else
    document.getElementById('ex').style.background ="green";

  }  
</script>
```